# Vue.js ES6 syntax error in switch case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I added a switch - case method when component is mounted, to handle Firebase emailhandler requests, I get a **syntax error** on the case..  ( unexpected token)
I dont understand why , as my statement seems to be correct ;

```
  mounted: {
    switch (mode) {
      case 'resetPassword':
        handleResetPassword(actionCode, continueUrl)
        break
      case 'recoverEmail':
        handleRecoverEmail(actionCode)
        break
      case 'verifyEmail':
        handleVerifyEmail(actionCode, continueUrl)
        break
      default:
        // Error: invalid mode.
    }
  },
```

thanks for feedback

Comment: `mounted: {` -> `mounted() {`, it's a function. Nothing to do with Vue

Comment: Oh yeah .. got it ! thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: For your next questions: *never* paraphrase the error message you get but add them as is and completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) is a Vue instance lifecycle hook. It is of type Function, and is called after the instance has been mounted.

Its syntax should be of the following format:

```
mounted: function () {
}
```

Or a shorter syntax since ECMAScript 2015:

```
mounted () {
}
```